# angular nested directive callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, callback

I have a list directive (actually a table, but that does not matter), where each element has a tools directive (select, edit, delete buttons). The tools directive gets callbacks for each action, so a specific controller can implement each action individually. Now it is not clear for me how pass the selected item to the controllers callback.
Any ideas on that?

The tools directive:

Javascript:
Here I define the callbacks

```
app.directive('itemTools', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  transclude: true,
  scope: {
    item: '=',
    selectCallback: '&',
    editCallback: '&',
    deleteCallback: '&',
    cloneCallback: '&',
    activateCallback: '&',
    deactivateCallback: '&',
  },

  link: function(scope, element, attr) {

  },
  templateUrl:'templates/common/item.tools.html',
  controller: function($rootScope, $scope) {
  }
}
```

});

HTML:

```
<div>
 <button ng-click="selectCallback({id: item.id})">
 </button>
 <button ng-click="editCallback({id: item.id})">
 </button>
 <button ng-click="deleteCallback({id: item.id})">
 </button>
 <button ng-click="cloneCallback({item: item})">
 </button>
 <button ng-click="activateCallback({item: item})">
 </button>
 <button ng-click="deactivateCallback({item: item})">
 </button>
</div>
```

The list directive:
these callbacks are handled further to the **item-tools**

```
app.directive('moduleList', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    modules: '=',
    selectCallback: '&',
    editCallback: '&',
    deleteCallback: '&',
    cloneCallback: '&',
    activateCallback: '&',
    deactivateCallback: '&',
  },
  templateUrl:'templates/module/module.list.html',
  controller: function($scope) {

  }
}
```

});

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort>
      <td class="text-center">
        SOME DATA OF THE OBJECT....
      </td>
      <td>
        <item-tools
        item="item"
        select-callback="selectCallback({id: item.id})"
        edit-callback="editCallback(item.id)"
        delete-callback="deleteCallback(item.id)"
        clone-callback="cloneCallback(item)"
        activate-callback="activateCallback(item)"
        deactivate-callback="deactivateCallback(item)">
        </item-tools>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I got it already so far, that the controllers function gets called, but I have no Idea how to pass in the selected item itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally, if you have nested directives, you must link the parent directive controller (see the angular example: https://plnkr.co/edit/xgrXXIbEQvqiGSQRebYQ?p=preview). You'll be basically opening up an API in the parent directive for the child directives to talk to. If you want your parent directive to talk to a controller, you can use $broadcast and listen for the events in the controller. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks, great idea to use events. But instead of **$broadcast** I prefer **$emit** in that case.

Answer (score 0):

child directives are linked to the parents by assigning the parent directive controller to the child:

```
// parent directive
app.directive('parentDirective', function() {
    return {
        controller: function() {
            this.hello = function() {
                return 'Hello World';
            };
        }
    };
});

// child directive
// you require the parent controller by the ^ctrlName
app.directive('childDirective', function() {
    return {
        require: '^parentDirective', // require the parent controller
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            // you have access to the parent API
            ctrl.hello(); // returns 'Hello World'
        }
    };
});
```